# Coldfusion 2016 websockets SSL connection fails

Tags: ssl, websocket, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am using coldfusion 2016 and trying to test secure websockets using a self signed cert generated in IIS and then imported to a jks keystore file.  In the coldfusion admin on the websocket page I have checked the secure box and entered the path to the jks keystore as well as password... I believe I have done this correctly bc it will scream at me if I enter the wrong password

```
keystore= C:\ColdFusion2016\jre\bin\websocket.jks
keystore password = changeit
```

I have tested on all browsers and they all fail to connect... for example in chrome:

```
cfwebsocketCore.js:21 WebSocket connection to 'wss://in001204.amcnt.amc.edu:8543/cfusion/cfusion' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I have imported the original pfx cert that I converted to jks into chrome but that doesn't help.

I have tried adding the tag below to the server.xml file and that didn't help

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"

       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"

       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"

       keystoreFile="C:\ColdFusion2016\jre\bin\websocket.jks"

       keystorePass="changeit"

       keystoreType="JKS" />
```

Comment: In the error message that you included it shows port 8543 but your connector is set to use port 8443. Is that just a typo here?

Comment: @gabriel Did you found any solution  ???